# Why is an unsaved parent class instance causing a NOT NULL constraint error when saving the child instance?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm following a tutorial of Pretty printed on youtube. During the tutorial he tries to instantiate a child model instance with a unsaved parent model instance called `Language`. But when he runs the code he gets an `IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: example_framework.language_id`

The narrator then explains that this is because he didn't call `save()` on the parent instance first leaving it without a primary key.  This is the code form the tutorial, and heres the youtube part where he encounters the error: https://youtu.be/2KqhBkMv7aM?t=440

```
java = Language(name='Java')
    spring = Framework(name='Spring', language=java)
    java.save()
    spring.save()
```

I don't understand why this gives an error though. Doesn't spring reference the same object that is referenced by the java variable? So if `save()` is called on java, shouldn't the Framework object referenced by the spring variable immediately have a primary key?

Comment: No, the primary key is fetched when you set the attribute. While what you describe could, strictly speaking, be possible, it is not implemented that way.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok, so the error occurs much sooner then `spring.save()` then, it occurs during instantiation of the Framework() object right? I still think its strange because at that point the `spring` variable itself has not yet been persisted to the database either. So the database integrity error is strange in this case.